# Illuminate Database QueryException PHP 8.1.18 9.52.10 could not find driver CREATE TABLE "products" filament

Tags: laravel-filament

## This is very strange ...i write this post to the filament comunity because in they are using php 8.0 in this example ...I continuing to resolve this problem.I check also the pdo_mysql extension that is enabled but yet dont work! if someone have a solution ? check this https://github.com/leandrocfe/filament-tables-json-data-source please

[image]

```
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Sushi\Sushi;
 
class Product extends Model
{
    use Sushi;
 
    /**
     * Model Rows
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function getRows()
    {
        //API
        $products = Http::get('https://dummyjson.com/products')->json();
 
        //filtering some attributes
        $products = Arr::map($products['products'], function ($item) {
            return Arr::only($item,
                [
                    'id',
                    'title',
                    'description',
                    'price',
                    'rating',
                    'brand',
                    'category',
                    'thumbnail',
                ]
            );
        });
 
        return $products;
    }
}
```

they do this this cause the error drive not found if you put a model instead this work so they code is not good they need repair this code.

Comment: If you want actual help on this site, this question is going to need alot of work, such as "no pictures"

Comment: Oviously filament force to use Model but why we don't use HTTP external resource to fill a table?

Comment: These seems like an Illuminate error.  What driver? Where is is asking to load one?  And if you mean .. the error is on line 52 .. why not post the code of the included php file cause that would be where the error is and is impossible to guess by a picture.

Comment: yes ! correct ! but this error is caused because filament is searching the model passed by url  http://site/Name-Of-Model so ...my question is : they give to me a repository git to test external api I've cloned this but thi don't work...because if I add the model to the resource as normal practice by guide it work .... Instead this https://github.com/leandrocfe/filament-tables-json-data-source NOT WORK I asking if some one have the same problem with this on laravel 10 thanks!

Comment: the problem drive is not fount is relative to eloquent they do this :

Comment: their guide https://filamentphp.com/blog/how-to-consume-an-external-api-with-filament-tables